# How do I set the expiration time for a key in IoRedis?

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I am connecting to a Redis sentinel using the code given below

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis({
    sentinels: [{ host: '99.9.999.99', port: 88888 }],
    name: 'mymaster'
});
```

I am setting the value of a key by using following code:

```
function (key, data) {

        var dataInStringFormat = JSON.stringify(data); /// conbverting obj to string

        /// making promise for returning
        var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            /// set data in redis
            redis.set(key, dataInStringFormat)
                .then(function (data) {
                    resolve(data);
                }, function (err) {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });

        return promise;

    }
```

Can you please help me by providing a solution to set an expire time for the key value e.g. 12 hours

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's documented

```
redis.set('key', 100, 'EX', 10)
```

Where `EX` and `10` stands for 10 seconds. If you want to use milliseconds, replace `EX` with `PX`

Comment: According to the documentation, `EX` for seconds, `PX` for milliseconds https://redis.io/commands/set